# me gustaria que me ayuden con este error:mysqli_num_rows()expectsparameter1tobemysqli_result,boolean given

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php

$alert="";
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['contraseña'])) {

            $alert="Ingrese su usuario y su clave";

        }else{


        require_once "conexion.php";

        $user = $_POST['usuario'];
        $pass = $_POST['contraseña'];

        $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM datos WHERE usuario='$user' AND contraseña='$pass'");

        $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if ($result>0) {

            $data = mysqli_fetch_text($query);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['active'] = true;
            $_SESSION['idUser'] = $data['id'];
            $_SESSION['nombre'] = $data['usuario'];



        }



        }

    }

?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<center>
    <form method="post">
        <h1>Iniciar Sesion</h1>
        Nombre de Usuario:<input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required><br><br><br>

        Contraseña<input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Ingrese Contraseña" required><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
        <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">

        <p class="alerta"> Mensaje</p>
</center>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Las preguntas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad porque las publicaciones sin un enunciado claro no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor lee [ask] y edita tu pregunta para añadir más información: qué es lo que hace el código, en que línea te da el error, cuál es el resultado esperado y el que obtienes.

Answer (score 2):

Te doy la bienvenida.

El código que presentas adolece de algunas incoherencias y le faltan algunos controles. Los voy a enumerar por orden de aparición  y luego te propondré una posible solución:

- No declares nunca variables antes de saber si las vas a usar
- No es necesario primero evaluar todo el `$_POST`
- Creo que la condición para ejecutar la consulta no debe ser *si hay datos en `usuario` O en `contraseña`*, sino *si hay datos en `usuario` Y en `contraseña`*, ya que ambos valores son usados en el `WHERE`
- Dado que la consulta está fallando, haremos verificación también sobre la conexión
- Tu código es inseguro, conviene usar consultas preparadas para evitar ataques de inyección SQL (recomiendo que leas sobre ello cuando puedas, es importante)
- Que yo sepa, mysqli no tiene un método `mysqli_fetch_text` ¡ ... !

Visto eso, vamos con el código:

```
<?php
    /*
        *Usamos ternarios para verificar el estado del POST
        *y de paso guardamos los datos en variables
        *para usarlas más adelante si fuera necesario
    */  
    $usuario =(empty($_POST['usuario']))    ? NULL : $_POST['usuario'];  
    $password=(empty($_POST['contraseña'])) ? NULL : $_POST['contraseña']; //Evitaría usar ñ     
    /*
        *Cambiamos la lógica para no hacer demasiado lío
    */
    if ($usuario && $password) {
        require_once "conexion.php";
        if ($conection){
            /*
                *Escribimos una consulta preparada
                *para evitar el riesgo de Inyección SQL
                *El código varía un poco, pero es necesario hacer esto
                *para no poner en riesgo los datos
            */
            $sql="SELECT id, usuario FROM datos WHERE usuario=? AND contraseña=?";
            if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conection, $sql)) {
                /*
                    *Pasamos a $stmt los datos aparte
                    *indicando con las ss con son datos de tipo cadena - (s)tring
                    *Luego ejecutamos 
                */
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $usuario,$password);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                /*
                    *Indicamos dos variables para cada columna del resultado
                    *que usaremos para ponerlas en la variable de sesión
                */
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $usr);
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                $totalFilas=mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

                if ($totalFilas>0){
                    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['active'] = true;
                        $_SESSION['idUser'] = $id;
                        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $usr;
                    }

                }else{
                    echo "No se encontraron filas";
                }

            }else{
               echo "Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conection);
            }

        }else{
            echo "No hay conexión disponible";
        }


    }else{
        echo "Ingrese su usuario y su clave";
    }
?>
```

He tratado de explicar todo en comentarios dentro del mismo código. Y tienes un programa controlado en todo momento, que informará debidamente sobre cualquier eventualidad.

Espero te sirva.